# Is there a function in R to combine names?

Tags: r, names

I have a list of 5 vectors.
The list is called VECT. The 5 vectors are called VA, VB, VC, VD, VE.
I have created a loop to add the vectors iteratively, getting VA+VA,VA+VB, VA+VC, VA+VD, VA+VE, VB+VA, VB+VB...
I want to insert a line of code so that no only are the resulting vectors produced under the console (already done), they are also named. Like "VA+VA", "VA+VB" etc.
How do I name like that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```r
VECT <- c("VA", "VB", "VC")
setNames(nm = c(outer(VECT, VECT, paste, sep = "+")))
#   VA+VA   VB+VA   VC+VA   VA+VB   VB+VB   VC+VB   VA+VC   VB+VC   VC+VC 
# "VA+VA" "VB+VA" "VC+VA" "VA+VB" "VB+VB" "VC+VB" "VA+VC" "VB+VC" "VC+VC"
```

Explanation:

- `outer` does an "outer product": it runs the function (3rd argument) on each pair from the two vectors. In this case, it is effectively the same as

  ```r
  for (nm1 in VECT) {
    for (nm2 in VECT) {
      paste(nm1, nm2, sep = "+")
    }
  }
  ```

  (and storing that in a vector)
- `c(...)`: `outer` returns a matrix (try it by itself!), so c(outer(...))` just unrolls it into a single vector.
- `setNames(nm = ...)` takes a vector and names it based on its values. Typical use is `setNames(object = vec, nm = vecnames)` which is equivalent to `names(vec) <- vecnames`, but when `object` is missing, then it defaults to self-naming.

If order is critical here, one can always sort it:

```r
sort(setNames(nm = c(outer(VECT, VECT, paste, sep = "+"))))
#   VA+VA   VA+VB   VA+VC   VB+VA   VB+VB   VB+VC   VC+VA   VC+VB   VC+VC 
# "VA+VA" "VA+VB" "VA+VC" "VB+VA" "VB+VB" "VB+VC" "VC+VA" "VC+VB" "VC+VC"
```